# SSRS main report calls subreport and ignores page breaks

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, reporting

I have a main report that has a subreport in there. That subreport has 4 other subreports built into one page and when I run the report from the main report, it ignores all the page breaks in the subreport. However, when I just run the subreport on its own, the page breaks work fine.

The main report generates a list of area locations (~10 locations) and that is passed as a text parameter to the subreport along with a date parameter. Using parameters (date + location), the subreport generates a list of records which it uses to create the subreport.

I'm starting to think this a design issue and thinking about re-designing it since my thoughts are that the subreport works fine on its own and losing all page breaks when called from the main report so I can attempt to try to re-design the entire report on the main report to see if that works.

Things I tried so far:

1. Keep Together = False
2. Page Break Options: Page break Between groups

[Main Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bU7Z.png)

[Subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBmvt.png)

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? That version went out of support *way* back in 2019; well over 4 years ago now. It is *long* past time you upgraded the version you are using.

Comment: You may want to remove the Crystal-Reports tag if this isn't related to an SAP reporting tool.  While SSRS is similar, they are distinctly different.